# C++ curl callback

Tags: c++, callback, libcurl

Can anyone inform me why we need a callback in some curl options, like `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`?

I used the code below in C++, and got the same result with or without a `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback, so it seems confusing to use a callback.

```cpp
int main(){
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode response;
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
        response=curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you please list some of these properties I’m still new to curl

Comment: [read the documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, libcurl simply writes the downloaded data to STDOUT.

If you just want to change which `FILE*` it writes the data to, you can use the [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) option.

But, if you want to change how it writes the data, for instance to write to something other than a `FILE*`, you can use a [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) callback.

For instance, see these examples, which use `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to customize downloads:

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/ftpsget.html

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http2-pushinmemory.html

Answer (score 0):

callback is an option that has it own specific properties that might be usefull for someone who wants to use that properties. see link below https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html